# Cannot find module ionic linux

Tags: ionic-framework

I took a project from my friend (mac) and I put this project on my pc (linux) but it didn't work. I tried but nothing.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/nihed/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids3/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/ionic-angular/app-scripts.js:9:16)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:103:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:99:16)
    at Object.importAppScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/ionic-angular/app-scripts.js:7:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should run `npm install` and `ionic cordova prepare` to install packages and plugins from the package.json.

Did you just copy node_modules directory too?

Comment: I think you shouldn't do that, it's not the right way. Delete the node_modules directory, then run `npm install`. The package.json file is here for that, I hope your friend used `npm install --save` when he installed packages :)